# Association created on all object when it should only be for 1 object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, associations, sails.js, waterline

I have a one to one association as described in the waterline doc:

```
// partie.js
score: {
  model: 'score'
}

// score.js
partie: {
  model: 'partie'
}
```

And I call this function which create a score and associate it to a partie at some point:

```
function addScore(partie_id, rez) {
  console.log("caaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaled");
  console.log(partie_id);
  Score.create({ array: rez, partie: partie_id }).exec(function (e, score) {
    Partie.update(partie_id, { score: score.id }).exec(function (err, data) {
      console.log("add scooooore");
    })
  });
}
```

So this should only create an association for the partie corresponding to the partie_id but it does create associations for ALL parties. I see the console.log only once so I'm sure this function is only called once. 
Any idea what could be happening here?

It's strange because if I open robomongo I see only the right partie has a score. But if I make a find in my code or check the blueprint then they're all there.

Comment: Does your console.log before `Score.create` display the correct value? If it happens to be an object `{}` then it would update ever Partie.

Comment: Yes it does, it's not an object, just a single ID

Comment: A few other thoughts, then: 

Do you have any beforeUpdate lifecycle callbacks in your model? 
Is Partie.count({partie: partie_id}) producing the same number as Partie.count()?

Comment: No beforeUpdate or anything. Didn't try the count but I think this is a bug in waterline. You can reproduce it using the one-to-one example code on the github repos. So basically I copy pasted that code and used it with sails-mongo and it still behave like I descibed. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1123

Comment: You mentioned robomongo, so you are working with MongoDB, so can you show us your model files for score and partie?